# Wordpress like Plugin Framework in ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net, wordpress

I am developing a CMS and I want to have a framework so anyone can plugin for it like the wordpress has.

I come to many solution but they are not that helpful.

Can anyone tell me a good solution...

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would probably start by looking at the Managed Extensibility Framework (http://www.codeplex.com/MEF).  It is designed to be an framework to build plug-ins in a way that is consistent across different applications (basically so you don't have to understand how each app does it's plug-ins).  It is, in fact, the method that Visual Studio 2010 is using for creating plug-ins.

Out of the box it gives you some nice features like monitoring directories for new plug-ins, and tracking dependencies.  It is still up to you to design the interfaces/contracts needed for people to create plug-ins for your system, but it takes the grunt work out of it.

Answer (score 0):

How about orchard?

http://orchard.codeplex.com/